# Unable to install CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have been installing various versions of CUDA this way for years:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge cuda --yes

# eg for 9.0:
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install cuda=9.0.176-1 --yes
```

This has always worked well, I had that in a script that would automatically setup my CI machines. But today I noticed that things aren't working anymore:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda=9.0.176-1 --yes
E: Unable to locate package cuda
```

**Apparently, the GPG key expired:** https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1081#issuecomment-533717708

To solve this, you now need to do:

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey |  sudo apt-key add -
```

**But still, same error!** I tried with CUDA version 10.0 as well but it fails in the same way.

Comment: the [documented](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.0/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#package-manager-metas) method to do this is `sudo apt-get install cuda-9-0`

Comment: Same result: `E: Unable to locate package cuda-9-0`

Comment: Follow the `Installation Instructions:` [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal).  Don't change anything except the last line.  Change the last line to: `sudo apt-get -y install cuda-9-0`

Comment: If there is no `cuda-9-0` package then try `cuda-toolkit-9-0`  But you will have to make sure a proper GPU driver is installed.

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cuda-10-0 --yes
```

The same approach works for CUDA 9.0. Not sure why my previous approach doesn't work anymore.

Comment: just curious, what is the different between `http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub` and `http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub`

Comment: 7fa2af80 is outdated @manaclan